# mostrar todos los datos de dos tablas mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, tablas, lógica

tengo dos tablas una de productos y otra de sala, en la tabla productos esta el total de todos los productos y en sala solo se encuentran algunos de ellos con su cantidad actual en "sala".
deseo unir las dos tablas que me muestra la cantidad de todos los productos de sala y todos los productos a la vez ejemplo:

[image: ------------------------- |id_poductos|descripcion| | 1 lápiz | | 2 cuaderno | | 3 goma | | 4 corrector | | 5 corchetera | -------------------------]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT id_productos, descripcion, cantidad    
FROM productos, sala       
WHERE id_productos = id_sala;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

deseo que esten los 5 productos aunque en la cantidad me los muestre como nulos o cero mostrando este resultado esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Investigaste algo sobre `JOIN` en SQL? ¿Has intentando algo al respecto? ¿Qué dificultad tienes? Falta un punto de partida en la pregunta.

Comment: no, como ejemplo ese el identificador del producto, pensando que "id_sala" es el mismo identificador del producto que se encuentra en otra tabla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id_productos, descripcion, cantidad    
FROM productos p 
left join sala s on p.id_productos = s.id_sala;
```

Puedes usar la **cláusula** **left join**, al usar esta cláusula se ponen los campos que relacionan ambas tablas si coinciden, y en caso de no coincidir se muestra la información de la tabla de la izquierda y la de la derecha se muestra como **null** .

Existen otras cláusulas para relacionar tablas como el **right join**, que es lo inverso al **left join**, el **inner join** que muestra solamente los registros que coinciden y el **full join** que combina las tres anteriores, es decir con este último obtendrías todos los registros de ambas tablas coincidan o no.

Comment: gracias me ayudaste en lo que necesitaba lo probare en un problema mas grande que tengo.